# Duplicate Objects in PFQueryCollectionViewController

Tags: swift, parse-platform, collectionview

I am fairly new to Swift and Parse and am attempting to use PFQueryCollectionViewController to load a set of images and titles. The problem is that my PFQueryCollectionViewCell is duplicating the same image and text label in the simulator although I have multiple objects within the class name I am querying. I have searched multiple discussion threads, but can't seem to find a solution that solves it. It's probably something super simple that I am overlooking but my eyes are starting to bleed!

Thanks in advance for your help.

**FeedViewController (PFQueryCollectionViewController)**

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import Parse
import ParseUI
import Bolts

let reuseIdentifier:String = "feedCell"

class FeedViewController: PFQueryCollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    let sectionInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10.0, left: 10.0, bottom: 10.0, right: 10.0)

        required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        // Configure the PFQueryCollectionView
        self.parseClassName = "Products"
        self.pullToRefreshEnabled = true
        self.paginationEnabled = true
        self.objectsPerPage = 50

    }

    override func queryForCollection() -> PFQuery {
        var query = PFQuery(className: "Products")
        query.orderByAscending("createdAt")

        return query
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: UICollectionViewDataSource

    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> PFCollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as? FeedViewCell

        let item = indexPath.item

        for object in objects {
        cell?.parseObject = object[item] as? PFObject
        if let parseObject = object["url"] as? String? {
        cell?.productImage?.image = nil
        if var urlString: String? = parseObject as String? {
            var url:NSURL? = NSURL(string: urlString!)

            if var url:NSURL? = NSURL(string: urlString!) {
                var error:NSError?
                var request:NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url!, cachePolicy: NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReturnCacheDataElseLoad, timeoutInterval: 5.0)

                NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().cancelAllOperations()

                NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), completionHandler: {
                    (response:NSURLResponse!, imageData:NSData!, error:NSError!) -> Void in

                    cell?.productImage?.image = UIImage(data: imageData) } )}
            } }

            cell?.title?.text = object["title"] as? String

            var text = object["title"] as? String

        }
        return cell!
        }

    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didEndDisplayingCell cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath ) {
        let cell = super.collectionView(collectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath: indexPath)
    }
   override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
        sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: 170, height: 300)
    }

    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
        insetForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    return sectionInsets
   }
}
```

**FeedViewCell (PFQueryCollectionViewCell)**

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import Parse
import ParseUI

class FeedViewCell: PFCollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var productImage: PFImageView?
    @IBOutlet weak var title: UILabel?

    var parseObject:PFObject?
}
```